# VIM custom command aliasing/mapping/transformation to existing command

Tags: vim

`:keep sometext` (Custom VIM command) -> `:%g!/sometext/d` (existing syntax)

How can the above transformation be achieved in VIM?

`:keep hello` -> `%g!/hello/d` (as an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this cmd a try:

```
 command! -buffer -nargs=1 Keep v/<args>/d
```

then you can `:Keep pattern`

`:h command` for details.